# Three.js shadow corresponds to bounding box, not actual model shape

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to get a correct-looking shadow for a dinosaur model (Three.js JSON format).

The shadow displays, but it's rectangular, as though it thinks the dinosaur model is just a simple cuboid (as screengrabbed below).

How can I generate a shadow that corresponds to the actual shape of the dinosaur?

I've checked in Blender that there's no containing box visible in the OBJ model, from which I created the JSON model file by using the Three.js OBJ to JSON converter.

Here's some snippets of the relevant pieces of code:

```
/* Dinosaur! */

var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

var filePath = 'models/trex/trex.js';

loader.load(filePath, function(geometry, materials) {

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry,
        new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );

    mesh.scale.set(1000, 1000, 1000);
    mesh.position.set( 0, -75, 0 );
    mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI;
    mesh.castShadow = true;

    scene.add( mesh );

});

...

/* Lights */

var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xFFFFFF );
scene.add( ambientLight );

var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xeeeeff, 0.5 );
directionalLight.position.set(0, 0, 1);
scene.add( directionalLight );

var spotlight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.2, 2000);
spotlight.position.set( 50, 100, 0 );
spotlight.target.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
spotlight.castShadow = true;
scene.add( spotlight );

...

/* Renderer */

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
renderer.setSize(renderWidth, renderHeight);

renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;

container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

...

/* Terrain */

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {

    heightData = buildHeightData(img);

    var plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 100, 100, HEIGHT_MAP_SIZE-1, HEIGHT_MAP_SIZE-1 );

    var l = plane.vertices.length;

    for( var i=0; i < l; i++ ) {
        // We change z because by default the plane will be placed vertically. 
        // We rotate it afterwards (so the effect on z will end up being the 
        // effect on y).
        plane.vertices[i].z = heightData[i] * 10;
    }

    terrainMesh = buildMesh(
        {
            geometry: plane,
            scale: 100,
            x: 0,
            y: -370,
            z: -1050,
            material: terrainMaterial
        } );

    terrainMesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
    terrainMesh.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add( terrainMesh );

};
img.src = 'img/heightmap.jpg';
```

p.s. I'm using Three.js v66.

[image: Screenshot of shadow]

Comment: Some code might help. How do you create the scene, load the dino, enable its shadow?

Comment: the model is copyrighted. You should not post it here or anywhere.

Comment: @gaitat OK... I've removed it. I did check with the content owner before posting it though.

Comment: ok then. that was not clear from your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops. I had jumped to an incorrect conclusion. It was just because the spotlight was not high enough (see new screengrab, with shadowCameraVisible = true).

[image]